# Find the specific number from Array.collect

Tags: ruby

I want to find out what's the first, the second, and the third result, so that I can do `if firstnumber==secondnumber && secondnumber==thirdnumber`. How could I find those numbers on the results?

```
numbers = 3.times.map { Random.new.rand(0..10000) }

prizes = numbers.map do |x|
  case x
  when 1..3000
    [ '7', 10000 ]
  when 3001..6000
    [ "Cherries", 500 ]
  when 6001..10000
    [ "Diamond", 400 ]
  end
end

puts "Your results are: #{prizes.collect { |p| p[0] }.join(", ")}!
```

I tried to use p[0][0], but it gives the first letter instead.

Comment: Your question might be clearer if it included the desired output.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need your expected output. You don't show how you attempted to solve the problem. Please try, then ask, instead of asking before trying.

Comment: One thing to note about these sorts of games is that the prize payouts depend on patterns, like `7,7,7` will payout substantially more per `7` than a single `7`.

Answer (score 2):

Say if:

```
results = prizes.collect { |p| p[0] } #=> ["Diamond", "Cherries", "7"]
```

Then do the following to get at each result:

```
results[0] #=> "Diamond"
results[1] #=> "Cherries"
results[2] #=> "7"
```

You could also use `results.first` to get the first element. If you happen to be working in Rails you can even do the following:

```
results.second #=> "Cherries"
results.third #=> "7"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fine way to do this:

```
numbers = 3.times.map { Random.new.rand(0..10000) }

prizes = numbers.map do |x|
  case x
  when 1..3000
    { name: '7', val: 10000 }
  when 3001..6000
    {name: "Cherries", val: 10000 }
  when 6001..10000
    {name: "Diamond", val: 400 }
  end
end

# You could replace 'map' with 'collect' here and have the same results
prizes_string = prizes.map { |p| "#{p[:name]}: #{p[:val]}" }.join(" and ")

puts "Your results are: #{prizes_string}!"
```

Comment: A bit of a misnomer here: `prizes_string` is actually an array of strings.

Comment: @tadman true, I fixed that

Comment: Using a hash to store things in an orderly manner works pretty well, but ends up being more verbose for such a small example. Could also explode the arguments: `prizes.map { |name, val| ... }` using the array pair.

Comment: A good practice would be to use Array.new(3) instead of 3.times.map.